# Simplest way to deal with "import" statement in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I’m using ANTLR4 and I have an "import" statement inside my grammar.

Does ANTLR4 have an option to automatically open and parse input file instead of doing it inside my visitor (creating another parser/lexer and visitor for each "import" declaration) ?

"Pretty" sure that I've already seen it but I can't find it anymore.

Inside my grammar :

```
importStatement : 'import' ID ';' // Here ? an action (Java code)
                                  // to prepend an AST to my current AST ?
```

Inside an input files :

```
Import test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this, primarily because every language requiring it has its own set of rules for how it needs to be done. In addition, this can quickly make the parse operation for your whole project go from O(n) to O(n²) (i.e. parsing each file once, to parsing up to the whole project for each file).

If your language allows you to build a correct parse tree prior to resolving the imports (e.g. it doesn't have arbitrary `#define` statements that can appear in imports), then you should be glad you aren't C/C++ and parse each file independently before resolving the import statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it's a frequently asked question. But I wasn't sure (especially in ANTLR4) if a common pattern exists (not necessarly a builtin just a java snippet maybe).
Even for a really naive implementation (while it does the job...).

But you're right a more specific, well designed and efficicent implementation is certainly better... :)